Adaptive Layout for all Screen sizes in Android Jetpack Compose
Login Page :
    [![@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun LoginPage(navController: NavController) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val homeScreen = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val loginScreen = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val mobileNumberState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val showToastState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var buttonClicked by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

    // Check the length of the mobile number
    val isMobileNumberValid = mobileNumberState.value.length == 10 && mobileNumberState.value.isDigitsOnly()
    var isFieldFocused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    Surface(
        color = Color(
            ContextCompat.getColor(
                context,
                R.color.pageBg
            )
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                .background(Color.White)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            Text(
                text = "Welcome Back!",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
                fontFamily = regular,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.scaapp),
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
            Text(
                text = "Let’s get Started",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineSmall,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.splashtext),
                fontFamily = regular
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.login), // Replace 'login' with your drawable file name
                contentDescription = "Splash Image",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .aspectRatio(1f)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = mobileNumberState.value,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                    capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.None,
                    autoCorrect = true,
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                ),
                label = {
                    Row(
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    ) {
                        Text("+91 ", fontFamily = semibold)
                        Text(
                            text = "Enter Your Mobile Number",
//                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
                            color = Color(
                                ContextCompat.getColor(
                                    context,
                                    R.color.placeholderColor
                                )
                            ),
                            maxLines = 1,
                        )
                    }
                },
                onValueChange = {
                    if (it.length <= 10) {
                        mobileNumberState.value = it.filter { char -> char.isDigit() } // This also ensures the input is only digits
                    }
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                    .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                        isFieldFocused = focusState.isFocused
                    },
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                    focusedBorderColor = if (isFieldFocused) {
                        if (mobileNumberState.value.length == 10) colorResource(id = R.color.scaapp) else Color.Red
                    } else colorResource(id = R.color.fieldBorder),
                    unfocusedBorderColor = colorResource(id = R.color.fieldBorder)
                )
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    val mobileNumber = mobileNumberState.value
                    if (mobileNumber.length == 10 && mobileNumber.isDigitsOnly()) {
                        showToastState.value = false
                        buttonClicked = true
                    } else {
                        showToastState.value = true
                        keyboardController?.hide()
                    }
                },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
               colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    containerColor = if (isMobileNumberValid) colorResource(R.color.scaapp) else colorResource(R.color.buttonDisable), // Set the background color
                    contentColor = Color.White // Set the text color
                )
            ) {
                Text("Sign in")
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            Row(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)) {
                Text(
                    "Don't have an account?",
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.black),
                    fontFamily = regular
                )
                Text(
                    " Register here",
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable { navController.navigate(ROUTES.SIGNUP.name) },
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.scaapp),
                    fontFamily = regular
                )
            }
        }
    }

    val prefDataStore = PreferenceDataStore(LocalContext.current)
    val accesstoken = runBlocking { prefDataStore.userName.first() }

    if (accesstoken.isEmpty()) {
        loginScreen.value = true
    } else {
        LaunchedEffect(true) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                prefDataStore.getDetails().collect {
                    if (it.name != "") {
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            homeScreen.value = true
                            navController.navigate(ROUTES.HOME.name)
                        }
                    } else {
                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            navController.navigate(ROUTES.LOGIN.name)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, device = Devices.DEFAULT)
@Composable
fun LoginPagePreview() {
    SCATheme {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        LoginPage(navController)
    }
}


when I check my UI in Start Check UI mode , 115%, 130 %, 180 % and 200 % screen sizes are always weird
As you can see "Don't have an account?" and " Register here" are not in single line except 100 % phone screen size
I also checked in real devices too...issue still exists
I need to show full text in single line without ...
"Enter Your Mobile Number" is also issue in many screens as you can see in image
How to adaptable for all screen sizes in android jetpack compose

The idea of larger text sizes (e.g. 200%) is to make the text better to read. Larger text consumes more space so not everything will fit into one line. You have to decide: Do you want to honor the user's wishes for better accessibility and allow the text to be larger (and therefore span multiple lines), or do you want to ignore that and keep the text size the same with the possible consequence that the user cannot use your app because they can't read the text anymore.

Instead of forcing the text to be smaller than the user wants I would suggest you embrace that and improve the line wrapping instead.

Also, the title of your question is misleading, your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Adaptive Layouts.
